# How to do a full exfat format in Linux (RaspberryPi)

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to do a full format as opposed to a quick format of a 500 GB exfat USB stick. mkfs.exfat seems to be just a quick format since it's immediately done.

The reason I want a full format is that files get corrupted when I copy them to the stick, but seemingly only after about 20 or 30 GB. chkdsk on windows always removes the corrupted files. I also checked for bad sectors, but none are found, same happens on a second PC, so it's probably not a driver issue. Right now I want to do a full format, which takes very long, but I don't want my PC to be on for two days (very slow stick), so I want to use my Raspberry Pi for it. I tried Gparted, but it doesn't support exfat. I feel like it should be pretty easy, just a command to format the stick in exfat, but no quick format

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It *may* be more appropriate on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You may have a fake USB device. One that reports a capacity of 500GB but only has 32GB and the mapping that makes it fake corrupts data.

Answer (score 1):

As [Dan says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415618/how-to-do-a-full-exfat-format-in-linux-raspberrypi#comment745986_415618), it is entirely possible that your flash drive is not truly 500GB if data constantly gets corrupted after 20-30GB has been written. I would recommend you test the drive to make sure it really can hold 500 GB using either a [Linux/OSX tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737473/check-real-size-of-usb-thumb-drive) or a [Windows tool](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/), whichever you feel comfortable with.

Comment: Won't `dd if=/dev/zero of=...` overwrite the on-device list of bad blocks? And I don't think the linux exfat driver supports creating an exfat filesystem with a badblocks list, based on https://github.com/relan/exfat/issues/79

Comment: @dgrogan Oh, thank you, I wasn't aware that wasn't in the exfat driver yet. And my formatting commands make no sense, formatting the ext, zeroing the drive, and then formatting to exfat makes no sense, I really have no clue what I was thinking. I will remove it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check `mkfs.exfat --help`:

```
$ mkfs.exfat --help
Usage: mkfs.exfat
    -L | --volume-label=label                              Set volume label
    -c | --cluster-size=size(or suffixed by 'K' or 'M')    Specify cluster size
    -b | --boundary-align=size(or suffixed by 'K' or 'M')  Specify boundary alignment
    -f | --full-format                                     Full format
    -V | --version                                         Show version
    -v | --verbose                                         Print debug
    -h | --help                                            Show help
```

You want the `--full-format` or `-f` option.